# Creating a tree from a list of item combinations

Tags: list, tree, combinations

I have n lists A,B,C... which contain a,b,c... elements. I'm using them to create a lists of possible combinations (list of lists), such that first element is taken from table A, second from B etc. What is the best way to transform this flat structure to a tree which root is followed by elements of list A, each having all elements of list B etc. thus creating every possible combination in a form of a path from the root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Algorithms

### 1: Going from the input

So if you have the lists `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]`, `[7, 8, 9]` you have [this list of possible permutiations](http://paste.ubuntu.com/706117/)

So I would now go through the lists and their elements. The all represent paths of the tree you want. So if everything was put into the tree, I would be able to find a node `1`, then move on to a `4` and then find a `7` at the third level. If I do not, I have to add this there.

```
paths = [
    [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9]
]

class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self.node = node
        self.children = []

    def addChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def toList(self):
        if len(self.children) > 0:
            return [self.node, [x.toList() for x in self.children]]
        else:
            return [self.node]

tree = Tree()

# iterate through the lists
for path in paths:
    subtree = tree

    for value in path:
        # check whether the current value already exists at this position in the tree
        found = False
        for child in subtree.children:
            if value == child.node:
                subtree = child
                found = True
                break

        # attach the leaf to the current position in the tree if needed
        if not found:
            newchild = Tree(node=value)
            subtree.addChild(newchild)
            subtree = newchild

        # use the found or created leaf as a position for the next value in the path-list

print tree.toList()
```

### 2: Back to the original lists

If the tree is as symmetric as it seems, you could also just slice the levels of the trees, giving you the list A, B and C. Then, you are back to square one and can build up the tree:

```
paths = [
    [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [1, 5, 9], [1, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [1, 6, 9], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8], [2, 5, 9], [2, 6, 7], [2, 6, 8], [2, 6, 9], [3, 4, 7], [3, 4, 8], [3, 4, 9], [3, 5, 7], [3, 5, 8], [3, 5, 9], [3, 6, 7], [3, 6, 8], [3, 6, 9]
]

lists = [[]]*len(paths[0])
for i in xrange(len(paths[0])):
    lists[i] = set([])
    for l in paths:
        lists[i].add(l[i])

def iterate(listnumber):
    result = []
    for element in lists[listnumber]:
        if listnumber < len(lists)-1:
            result.append([element, iterate(listnumber+1)])
        else:
            result.append([element])
    return result

tree = iterate(0)

print tree
```

It goes through each layer of the pile of lists (a, b, c) and stores the unique members in a list. Then it has the lists A, B, C and generates the tree out of it.

## Result

This is the tree I get, 0 is the artificial root. The nodes are "recycled" since they all bear the same content. (Made with [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/).)

http://wstaw.org/m/2011/10/11/tree.png

Comment: The problem is, I'm working on lists of combinations, not original A,B,C.. lists. To use your solution I would need to undo the combinations step. The language is C++, but it's really more of a generic algorithm question.

Comment: Okay, so you have `[1, 4, 7]`, `[1, 4, 8]`, ..., `[1, 5, 8]`? That would be list_elements**list_number elements, right?

Comment: I generated lots of list, would it be [this here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/706117)?

Comment: In this case I have [1, 4, 7], [1, 4, 8], ... [3, 6, 9], that's a * b* c (3 * 3 * 3) lists of n (3) elements.

Comment: I revised my answer, trying to build a prototype.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without reverting to original A,B,C lists?

Comment: I think my the first algorithm in the answer would do, I'm currently working on a prototype and it takes a while :)

Comment: I got it working now, I had to define my own tree structure as I was not succeeding with the nested lists alone. Both programs output the same as my very first one.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :(